# May someone with a monotonic voice be a Ba'al Kri'ah?

Tags: halacha, technology, torah-reading

I understand that the main purpose of trope is grammatical. The musical aspect, as I understand is secondary.

Halachically, when one reads the Torah publicly, is one **required** to sing it with the trope? (If he is able to do so?)

What about someone who has an [artificial larynx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolarynx) sounds monotonic. As long as he knows to pause at the end of each verse (so at least this is a signal that he distinguishes the grammatical usage of the trope to the best of his voice ability), would he be allowed to be a *Ba'al Kri'ah*?

Please address both:

- If someone else is available, but the monotonic person is more qualified, e.g., he is the shul's hired Ba'al Kri'ah, and he was injured.
- No one else is available

Comment: Why would you think such a person shouldn't be allowed to read the Torah?

Comment: Could he be chazzan on rosh hashana? Seemingly he shouldn't be if there's someone else available.

Comment: @Daniel Refer to my 2nd paragraph.

Comment: @DanF That's my question. Why would you think it might be the case that it is required to sing the Torah with the trope?

Comment: I think it is preferred that he sing it with melody. But if not, accurate reading would suffice.

Comment: See Megillah 32a

Comment: I guess he is reffuring to http://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.32a.12

Comment: http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.142.2?with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang=bi

Comment: Is someone who talks with an artificial larynx halachically considered talking? Maybe it's no different than talking into a microphone/telephone/other electronic device, in which R' Moshe says one cannot fulfill a mitzvah by listening under such circumstances. Perhaps here, too, an electronic larynx would not be fit for listening to Kerias HaTorah.

Comment: @DonielF If you can provide a link to this issue, I'd like to get its context. Regarding Torah reading, I don't think the issue is talking. At least in my question, the issue is the ability to sing. The question addresses anyone with a monotonic voice or the inability to sing trope, not specifically someone who has an artificial larynx.

Comment: @Daniel as DoubleAA pointed, "See Megillah 32a". B"N, I'll try to edit that factor in, later.

Comment: @DanF I understand what your question is. Mine is whether he would even be qualified to read in the first place, before we take into account whether he can sing. The kehillah might not be yotzei with him. I don't have the exact teshuvah, but he says it with regard to kerias hamegillah.