# How much speech capacity is required to have an aliya or daven from the amud?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, speech-talking, handicap-disabled-impair

A person who has had the voicebox removed (due to cancer, for example) can still have a bit of speech, and it's not necessarily quiet. The main thing is that it doesnt sound like normal speech.  Can such a person have an aliya, daven before the amud, or be motsi others, or must speech go through the voicebox to count for those purposes?  What sources are applicable to the question?

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14478/759

Comment: https://www.urmc.rochester.edu/encyclopedia/content.aspx?ContentTypeID=34&ContentID=22953-1

Comment: Somewhat related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83679/may-someone-with-a-monotonic-voice-be-a-baal-kriah

Comment: There it discusses an electronic larynx. There are other  ways as my article shows without any electronic aids.